# How to force an application that autostarts from CD to run in "Compatibility Mode"

Tags: windows, windows-xp, autorun

We distribute an app that needs to be run in XP Compatibility mode on Vista 64 bit.
But it autostarts (it runs from a CD) not from a shortcut.

Anyone know how to force it to start in XP Compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=force+xp+compatibility+mode&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) gave me [this](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?postid=2075919#post2075919)

> For those of you who want to force an app to run in XP compatibility mode, just set the following registry key:

```
HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" "[full application path goes here]" "WINXPSP2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold down SHIFT while placing CD in drive.

Browse to CD, right click on EXE file (you may have to read AUTORUN.INF to find it).

I think you can do it in properties. If not, make a shortcut.